# How to separate nested subexpressions to list?

Tags: expression-manipulation

I have an expression like this:

```
3*Subscript[v, 0]^3*Subscript[v, 1]^8*Subscript[v, 2]^7*Subscript[v, 3]^2
```

I would like to extract the exponents and put them into a list sorted by the subscript and separate the constant factor. So I would like to have an output like this:

```
{3, {3,8,7,2}}
```

And in case the constant is missing in the expression, it should be output as 1, naturally.
How can I achieve this? I tried sequence patter matching, but I did not succeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use

`CoefficientRules`

and get

> {{3, 8, 7, 2} -> 3}

If we call your expression `a`  then this should do the work

```
##&@@@CoefficientRules@a
```

> {{3, 8, 7, 2}, 3}

Answer (score 0):

Try this (`expr` is your expression):

```
expr /. Times -> List /. {a_Integer, b__} :> {a, {b}}
MapAt[Total@Outer[Exponent, #, Array[Subscript[v, #] &, 4, 0]] &, %, 2]
```